# ¿Cómo puedo obtener información del usuario desde javascript si su zona horaria es UTC, GTC o etc?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo obtener la información del usuario, para saber que zona horaria tiene, por ejemplo: Ultima conexión 1:24 PM UTC, algo como eso pero en este código

````
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'              

if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
}

document.write( + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm);```
````

Answer (score 0):

Las siguientes son funciones de los objetos DateTime.

Para tener una idea de la zona horario, usa la función [`getTimeZoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset). Obtendrás el desfase entre tu zona horaria y UTC en minutos.

Para obtener un string con un mensaje similar al que buscas prueba con la función [`toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString).

De la misma manera que obtienes cosas concretas de un objeto Date, como los segundos, minutos, horas y demás, puedes obtenerlos en UTC agregándoles la palabra `UTC` luego de `get` en su nombre.

Un ejemplo con tu código:

```
var hours = currentTime.getUTCHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getUTCMinutes();
```

Puedes consultar más funciones de Date [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Bien, pero obtengo números, y lo que necesito es hacerlo para obtener texto, algo como esto https://ibb.co/ctBHBPq

Comment: Agregué algo más de información a la respuesta. Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Usa la libreia date-fns time zone
https://date-fns.org/v2.27.0/docs/Time-Zones

tiene varias funciones para obtener diferencias entre dos fechas
https://date-fns.org/v2.27.0/docs/differenceInHours

```
import { formatInTimeZone } from 'date-fns-tz'

const date = new Date('2020-10-25T10:46:20Z')

formatInTimeZone(date, 'America/New_York', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX') // 2020-10-25 06:46:20-04:00
formatInTimeZone(date, 'America/New_York', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz') // 2020-10-25 06:46:20 EST
formatInTimeZone(date, 'Europe/Paris', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz') // 2020-10-25 10:46:20 GMT+2
```